# Submit cell data from table in thymeleaf template

Tags: thymeleaf

I have following code snippet:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Title</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr th:if="${list.isEmpty()}">
    <td colspan="2">No Media Available</td>
</tr>
<tr th:each="media : ${list}">
    <form th:action="@{/pages}" method="post">
        <td><span th:text="${media.getType()}">Type</span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${media.getTitle()}">Title</span></td>
        <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="add"/></td>
    </form>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now to my question: How can I submit the content from the rows?

Another question: Is my approach to creating a form for each row makes sense at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have user-entered data sent to the server, then replace this:

```
<td><span th:text="${media.getTitle()}">Title</span></td>
```

with this:

```
<td><input name="title" th:value="${media.title}"></td>
```

Assuming the `${media.title}` evaluates to "War and Peace" This will use the `name` field to submit data as `title=War and Peace` (with URL encoding for the spaces in the title: `War%20and%20Peace`).

Note the use of `${media.title}` instead of `${media.getTitle()}`. You should be able to refer to the field name, rather than the `get` method. Thymeleaf will use the `getFoo()` method for a field called `foo`, based on naming conventions.

There are other approaches, for example:

- use a visible input field, but styled to look and behave like regular text (cannot be edited, and has no surrounding box).
- use JavaScript to replace the default form submission process, and read your row data from the vanilla table, without a form - instead, with a button using a click event handler.

If you create one form for the entire table, you're going to get all the table's data submitted at once (arrays of `title` data, and so on).

Alternatively, if you have one form per table row, you have to consider what happens if a user edits multiple rows of data before hitting `submit` for one row. All those other unsent changes will potentially be lost.

A common solution is to avoid this problem, by forcing users to update records one at a time: The table does not use forms. Each row's button click opens a new modal dialog containing the data for only that one row (in a form) - which can then be edited and submitted.